# cant return a string from function

Tags: c++

The problem i am having is when i compile my code, i get an error (uninitialized local variable "optionNumber used"

I am using visual studio 2017 on a macbook air for this.

here is my code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int runMenu(int optionNumber) {
    std::cout << "Choose an option \n";
    std::cout << "1) Create Array \n";
    std::cout << "2) View Array \n";
    std::cout << "3) Add/Delete Values \n";
    std::cin >> optionNumber;
    return(optionNumber);

};

int main()
{   
    int optionNumber;
    int optionNum;
    optionNum = runMenu(optionNumber);
    std::cout << optionNum;
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: Which part of the compiler's message did you not understand?

Comment: it runs fine on my computer. I ran it on terminal with g++. Can you try running using your terminal and check if the error is due to VS?

Comment: Is there a reason why `optionNumber` is a parameter? Shouldn't it be a local variable?

Comment: In `main()`, `optionNumber` is uninitialised so accessing its value gives undefined behaviour.   It's value is then passed to `runMenu()`, so that uninitialised variable is being used (its value accessed).   Hence the compiler *warning*.   (The behaviour is not formally required to be diagnosed, so most compilers will still compile the code).

Comment: Did you really get an error, or was it a warning?  What line of your code was it pointing to?  It's important to read the compiler messages carefully to understand what they are saying.

Comment: "cant return a string from function" - If you want to return a `string`, why is your function then written to return `int` and not `string`?

Comment: @rhn89 Just because it runs fine doesn't mean the code is correct. It's perfectly possible for programs with undefined behavior to appear to work properly. Also note that compilers are very rarely wrong, especially with basic things like this, so don't blame the compiler unless you're absolutely sure beyond any reasonable doubt that your code is correct, ideally after consulting with others.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int main()
> {   
>     int optionNumber;
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Here, you've declared a local variable. You've not provided an initialiser. Therefore the local integer has an indeterminate value. If you read an indeterminate value, the behaviour of your program will be undefined.

> ```
> optionNum = runMenu(optionNumber);
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Here, you copy the variable whose value is indeterminate into an argument. Therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined. Luckily, your compiler noticed this mistake and warned about it.

Most trivial solution: Initialise the variable:

```
int optionNumber = 42;
```

On the other hand, you may want to think a bit about what you've written. The value that you pass to the function `runMenu` is never used in the function. Whatever value is passed in will be overwritten by whatever is extracted from standard input. The argument is completely pointless. Instead of an argument, you can read the input into a local variable:

```
int runMenu() {
    // your std::cout stuff
    int optionNumber;
    std::cin >> optionNumber;
```